# Account "lost" after using --datadir in Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, accounts, addresses, datadir

I am extremely new to Ethereum, just started mining a bit 2 days ago. I use Windows 10 and a GeForce GTX 950 card.
I have had geth running smoothly for about 2 days, then it started filling up my AppData in my C drive, leaving only 4 GB of space left.

Out of desperation, I did something very stupid by trying to copy the entire AppData folder to my other drive and then I used `geth --datadir` to try to direct the huge amounts of file storage go into my other drive. When I tried to run Geth, it didn't work, so I `used --datadir` again to swap it back to my C drive and deleted my entire copied AppData folder on my other drive.

When I did `geth --rpc` again, it said no etherbase set and no accounts found as default

[image]

and when I do the `ethminer.exe -G` on another window, errors pop saying I have no set etherbase.

I have been mining for 2 days and I know it's not too much, but yesterday when I checked I had a bit of ether by using `eth.getBalance` and I know all my keys and passwords and addresses and stuff are all here somewhere, but I just don't know where and how to use etherbase and re-set it up.

I tried to log in again using `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "password")` but it cannot find my account. I don't even know where and how geth stores a local account.

I have my local account address on a sticky note it looks like
af104bda8 etc etc 
(I don't think that's a key)
and I remember my passphrase, my keystore folder had a file in it but after I tried copying AppData to another drive the file inside disappeared.

I'm very lost what do I do?

Comment: what is the content of C:\Users\cheng\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum?

Comment: @BadrBellaj it has a geth folder and a keystore folder, the keystore folder is empty and the geth folder has ethash, node data and a huge folder of chaindata

Answer (score 1):

First run geth normally without datadir, e.g., `geth console`

Then check your accounts using : `personal.listAccounts`
It should display you all your accounts. When you've started geth for the first time without `--datadir` your private keys(accounts) and your blockchain are stored under

```
%APPDATA%\Ethereum (\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum) 
keystore : for private keys
chaindata: blockchain copy
```

so to use another location move this folder (Ethereum) elsewhere and use its new location in `--datadir`

Comment: My keystore folder is empty and personal.listAccounts gave me a blank [ ] as output when i did it in geth console

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moving the keystore directory I would "copy" it to the new location and additionally store a backup copy in a cold storage location.